# Why is Cocoapods pod spec lint (FAILING while) trying to build code when my podspec is only there to package a vendored_framework?

Tags: ios, ruby, cocoapods, podspec

So I [forked this repo to here](https://github.com/horseshoe7/BRPtouchPrinterKit) because the original didn't push its podspec anywhere.

And now I know why that developer didn't push it... it doesn't pass `pod spec lint ...`

And why doesn't it pass pod spec lint... ?

The .podspec is aiming to wrap a vendored_framework into a pod so it brings all dependency management under one system, hopefully thereby minimizing build-time problems.

The issue is, if you look at this podspec, there is no source.  No Xcode project.  Just a vendored_framework and some resources.

So I don't understand why I got this when running `pod spec lint --verbose BRPtouchPrinterKit.podspec`

I omitted **a lot** of console spew here.  Basically cloning the above repo and running the pod spec lint command will reproduce the issue.

```
    The following build commands failed:
        Ld /Users/mhp-oconnor/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/App-hjbzfnrwnwjtowbhgukgevlhcnks/Build/Intermediates.noindex/App.build/Release-iphonesimulator/App.build/Objects-normal/x86_64/Binary/App normal x86_64
    (1 failure)
   Testing with `xcodebuild`. 
 -> BRPtouchPrinterKit (3.1.9)
    - ERROR | [iOS] xcodebuild: Returned an unsuccessful exit code.
    - NOTE  | xcodebuild:  note: Using new build system
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Planning build
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  note: Constructing build description
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  ld: warning: ignoring file BRPtouchPrinterKit/Frameworks/BRPtouchPrinterKit.framework/BRPtouchPrinterKit, missing required architecture i386 in file BRPtouchPrinterKit/Frameworks/BRPtouchPrinterKit.framework/BRPtouchPrinterKit (3 slices)
    - NOTE  | [iOS] xcodebuild:  warning: Skipping code signing because the target does not have an Info.plist file and one is not being generated automatically. (in target 'App' from project 'App')

Analyzed 1 podspec.

[!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error.

/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command/spec/lint.rb:95:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/claide-1.0.2/lib/claide/command.rb:334:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/lib/cocoapods/command.rb:52:in `run'
/usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0/gems/cocoapods-1.8.4/bin/pod:55:in `<top (required)>'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `load'
/usr/local/bin/pod:23:in `<main>'
```

Comment: Probably because of an unsupported architecture: `missing required architecture i386 in file` If you can access the source, you can probably re-compile it to support i386 and then it will probably work (assuming no complications)

Comment: I have no access to the vendored_framework source so I'm not sure what I need to do.